# If Statement in for loop only returns true once?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

```
private List<Double[]> bestPoints(List<Double[]> includedPoints) {
        List<Double[]> bestPoints = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
        int a = includedPoints.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            Double[] tempPoint = includedPoints.get(i);

            if (tempPoint[2] == maxCount) {
                bestPoints.add(new Double[] {tempPoint[0], tempPoint[1]});
            }
        }

        return bestPoints;
    }
```

In this case

```
a = 17
maxCount = 2.0
```

and

`tempPoint[2]` in this case is `2.0` every time

but the debugger shows that

> bestPoints.add(new Double[]
>   {tempPoint[0], tempPoint[1]});

Only gets ran once as if the if statement was not true? Why?

Comment: Are you *sure* it's 2.0, and not 1.999999999...? Using `==` on `double` is a very risky operation.

Comment: He's not using == on a `double` ... he's using it on a `Double`, which is the problem. It's comparing the reference value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very likely doing a reference equals rather than a comparison equals. When using the capital lettered versions of the numeric types, you should use `one.equals(two)`.

Ensure that the value of `tempPoint[2]` is **exactly** `2.0`. As a `double`, it's very possible that they are close, but not equal.

You also might find using a foreach loop easier to follow:

```
private List<Double[]> bestPoints(List<Double[]> includedPoints) {
    List<Double[]> bestPoints = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
    for (Double[] tempPoint : tempPoints) {
        if (tempPoint[2] == maxCount) {
             bestPoints.add(new Double[] { tempPoint[0], tempPoint[1] });
        }
    }

    return bestPoints;
}
```

If the values are always integers, then cast them before checking equality (e.g., `(long)tempPoint[2] == (long)maxCount`). If you want exact matches from `double`s, then continue what you are doing (after ensuring the proper type of equal check, dependent on maxCount), but if you want *near* matches (if decimals are a concern rather than predefined constants), then use an epsilon value:

```
public static boolean doubleEquals(double val1, double val2, double epsilon)
{
    return Math.abs(val1 - val2) < epsilon;
}

public static boolean doubleEquals(double val1, double val2)
{
    return doubleEquals(val1, val2, 1e-5);
}
```

Obviously specify an epsilon value that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the condition you are trying to match the references of the Double object instead you should use if(tempPoint[2].compareTo(maxCount)==0).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using "java.lang.Double". They are objects. Assuming maxCount is also Double

To compare two objects use

equals()

```
d1.equals(d2)
```

another option is to use "compareTo())

```
d1.compareTo(d2)
```

the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.

Read more here 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 0):

To compare two double primitive values use compare(double d1, double d2) method of Double class. This is a static method. It returns 0 if both the values are equal, returns value less than 0 if d1 is less than d2, and returns value grater than 0 if d1 is grater than d2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are quite sure that `tempPoint[2]` is always `new Double(2.0)`, and if `maxCount` is a primitive double, e.g. `double maxCount = 2.0;` rather than `Double maxCount = new Double(2.0)`, the if condition should succeed. Otherwise you may use `if (tempPoint[2].equals(maxCount))` instead which does `if (tempPoint[2].doubleValue() == maxCount.doubleValue())`